# trouble in usage of the generic methods

Tags: java, generics

I have a method declared as below

```
<T> T getAdapter(Adaptable adaptable, Class<T> extensionInterface);
```

and I'm calling it with below argumants

```
adapterManager.getAdapter(new AWScoreAdapterImpl(null), AWScoreAdapter.class);
```

Can someone help me understand why the above line is causing the below compile time error

> The method getAdapter(Adaptable,
>   Class) in the type AdapterManager
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (AWScoreAdapterImpl,
>   Class)

Comment: Based on the `Class<T>` this looks to be Java? I am adding a Java tag, please fix the tags if my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `AWScoreAdapterImpl` and `AWScoreAdapter` classes (at least the class declaration line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with generics - your `AWScoreAdapterImpl` isn't of type `Adaptable`. Either implement its interface, or extend it if it's a class.

Are you able to post your class definitions here? In particular, `Adaptable`, `AWScoreAdapterImpl` and `AdapterManager`.

Comment: yep thats true...learning too much of generics and it is always the first suspect ;-)